# How to include SASS styles in an angular 8 library

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-library

I had an angular library for sharing some components, directives and more between two projects.

Recently I tried to include in the library some styles to reuse in the two projects but I can achieve to ng build include it in the bundle.

¿Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I found until now is to run an npm script to copy sass files on dist folder (using copyfiles) before package the .tgz for internal use.

**Here my package.json:**

```
{
...
     "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e",
        "uiutils_build": "ng build my-library",
        "uiutils_styles": "copyfiles -f projects/my-library/src/scss/*.scss dist/@my-namespace/my-library/scss",
        "uiutils_pack": "cd dist/@my-namespace/my-library && npm pack",
        "uiutils_copy": "copyfiles -f dist/@my-namespace/my-library/*.tgz ../infraestructure.tourbitz.com/packages/@my-namespace/my-library",
        "uiutils_package": "npm run uiutils_build && npm run uiutils_styles && npm run uiutils_pack && npm run uiutils_copy"
      },
...
}
```

the important script is uiutils_styles.

**¿How to use?**

In my style files, I included the styles:

```
@import "~@my-namespace/ui-uitils/scss/my_style.scss";
```

And for registering global styles I did on the project section of the angular.json file:

```
{
... 
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
"styles": [
              "node_modules/@my-namespace/my-library/scss/my_style.scss",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
...
},
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update for Angular 9**:

In the library, next to the `lib`-directory, create a `styles`-directory and then add it as assets to `ng-rollout.yaml` like so:

```
"assets": [
  "styles/**/*.scss"
]
```

This will copy all SCSS-files found recursively in the `styles`-directory into a `styles` directory in the output directory of your library.